# Can't change the background of an iframe

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to change the background of an iframe that contains Google. But I can't. Any suggestions ?

```
<script>
function changeFrame() {
    var oIframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    var oDoc = oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument;
    if (oDoc.document) {
        oDoc = oDoc.document;
    }
    oDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = "#00f";
    return true;
}
</script>

<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, it would be in violation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents you from accessing and modifying content on another domain.

> In computing, the *same origin policy* is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, **but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites**.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rule of javascript in web browsers that a script sourced from one domain may not manipulate the DOM of another domain, even when that other domain is shown in an iframe.  This is called Same Origin Policy.

So I'm afraid this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

this is a wherry common question :D

your not allowed to interact with content from
other domains then your own in javascript